ng-apexcharts PieChart overlapping legend
I am using ng-apexcharts for my angular project and encapsulated a piechart inside a certain component.
For some reason sometimes when refreshing the page the piechart is overlapping the legend after data is loaded to the chart (screenshot). The chart is only rendered when the data is not null using ngIf.

And this is the chart config that is used. The bug only appears on screens width larger than 1100 when the legend is configured to be to the right of the piechart.
{
    "chart": {
        "width": "480",
        "height": "300",
        "type": "pie",
        "events": {}
    },
    "stroke": {
        "width": 1
    },
    "legend": {
        "show": true,
        "position": "right",
        "itemMargin": {
            "horizontal": 0,
            "vertical": 6
        },
        "floating": false
    },
    "dataLabels": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "responsive": [
        {
            "breakpoint": 2600,
            "options": {
                "chart": {
                    "width": "480",
                    "height": "300",
                    "type": "pie",
                    "events": {}
                },
                "stroke": {
                    "width": 1
                },
                "legend": {
                    "show": true,
                    "position": "right",
                    "itemMargin": {
                        "horizontal": 0,
                        "vertical": 6
                    },
                    "floating": false
                },
                "dataLabels": {
                    "enabled": false
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "breakpoint": 1100,
            "options": {
                "chart": {
                    "width": "100%",
                    "height": "300",
                    "type": "pie",
                    "events": {}
                },
                "stroke": {
                    "width": 1
                },
                "legend": {
                    "show": true,
                    "position": "bottom",
                    "itemMargin": {
                        "horizontal": 2,
                        "vertical": 4
                    },
                    "floating": false
                },
                "dataLabels": {
                    "enabled": false
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "series": [
        564,
        8,
        6,
        194
    ],
    "labels": [
        "Streaming",
        "Messaging",
        "Social Media",
        "Other"
    ],
    "colors": [
        "#6635CD",
        "#0085FF",
        "#4ACDD1",
        "#CCC3D5"
    ]
}


I think there are some missing bits in the configuration object you posted: the legend labels are not the default ones - there must be a formatter; the chart options width: "480", height: "300", that should be in effect, are not the sizes of the chart in the image you attached. I could only reproduce your issue using these options - the outer div is constraining the width of the chart; the most important legend option there is floating: true - are you sure that this is not set in your actual configuration? If it is, the solution is to set it false.
